# Stop Reduce function in Hadoop on condition

Tags: hadoop, reduce

I have a reduce function where i want to halt the reduce function after processing some 'n' keys. I have set a counter to increment on each key, and on condition being satisfied return from the reduce function.

Here is the code

```
    public class wordcount {

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
        private IntWritable leng=new IntWritable();

 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
         while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String lword=tokenizer.nextToken(); 
            leng.set(lword.length());
             context.write(leng, one);
             }
        }
    } 

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

    int count=0;
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
         throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
        count++;
         }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        if(count>19) return;
            }

    }
```

Is there any other way that I achieve this.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you have more than one reducer, you cannot handle the processed keys limit internally. For example, if you wanted to stop after 10 keys, but you had 2 reducers, you'd end up processing 20 keys in total. You'll need to control this limit externally from wherever you are starting the job from.

Comment: I am using a single reducer to achieve my condition of top n keys required. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the `run()` of the Reducer class (New API)

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

  //reduce method here

  // Override the run()
  @override
  public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    int count = 0;
    while (context.nextKey()) {
        if (count++ < n) {
        reduce(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getValues(), context);
        } else {
            // exit or do whatever you want
        }
    }
    cleanup(context);
  }
}
```